# Помощь с переполнением массива

Tags: c++, c

Пишу код работающий с шифровкой Вижинера. Во время ввода ключа для шифрования, возникает проблема, из-за которой переполняется массив с этим же ключом, и не могу двигаться дальше, уже всю голову сломал.

При вводе ключа, он должен записываться в массив key, после чего использоваться в функции Encryption_Viz, но возникает переполнение.

> Ссылка на скриншоты: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPTCJ.jpg

Проект:
http://cpp.sh/9zern

Или так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define STR_LEN 100

char alphavite[] =  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstvuwxyz";

void Input_By_File(char *started_string)
{
    FILE* pFile;
    char mystring[100];

    pFile = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    if (pFile == NULL) perror("\nError opening file");
    else {
        if (fgets(mystring, 100, pFile) != NULL) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < STR_LEN; i++) 
            {
                started_string[i] = mystring[i];
            }
            puts(started_string);
        }
        fclose(pFile);
    }
}

void Input_By_Yourself(char* started_string)
{
    getchar();

    gets_s(started_string, STR_LEN);
    printf(">Вы ввели строку:      '%s'\n\n", started_string);
}

void Output_Start_Info()
{

    printf("                Добро пожаловать в программу для шифровки/расшифровки текста!\n\nВ нашей программе представлен следующий виды шифрования:");
    printf("\n\n");
    printf(">Шифр Вижинера\n");
}

void Input_Start_String(char* started_string)
{
    int key;

    printf("\n\nВыбирете метод ввода данных: \n1 — Ввести вручную\n2 — Загрузить из файла\n");
    scanf_s("%i", &key);
    switch (key)
    {
    case 1: printf("\n\nПожалуйста введите текст, который хотите де-/за-шифровать, на английском языке: "); Input_By_Yourself(started_string);
        break;
    case 2: printf("\n\nПроисходит загрузка файла (text.txt) с текстом, который хотите де-/за-шифровать.\n"); printf("Ваш файл содержит следующую строку: ");  Input_By_File(started_string);
        break;
    default: printf("Вы ввели неправильный ключ, попробуйте сначала.");
        break;
    }

}

int Input_Type_of_Encryption() 
{
    int key = 0;
    printf("\n\nПожалуйста, введите номер вида шифрования, который вы хотите использовать для данной строки: ");
    scanf_s("%i", &key);

    return key;
}

int Type_Of_Work()
{
    int key;
    printf("\n\nПожалуйста, выберите тип выполняемой работы:\n1 — Зашифровать текст\n2 — Расшифровать текст\n");
    scanf_s("%i", &key);

    return key;

}

/*char Key_For_Encryption()
{
    char key[STR_LEN + 1] = "";
    printf("\n\nВведите ключ для шифрования: ");

    Input_By_Yourself(key);

    return key[STR_LEN];
}*/


void Encryption_Viz(char *started_string, char *encrypte_string)
{
    char key[STR_LEN] = "";
    printf("\n\nВведите ключ для шифрования: ");

    Input_By_Yourself(key);




    char long_string[] = " ";

    int s = strlen(started_string);
    int e = strlen(key);



    if (s >= e)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
        {
            long_string[i] = key[((e+1)%(i+1))];
        }
    }

    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
        {
            long_string[i] += key[i];
        }
    }

    printf("%s ", long_string);

}

int Decryption(char* text, int k, char* key, int a, int j) 
// text - шифр-текст, key- ключ, k - длина блока text, a - длина ключа, j - каков будет размер блока расшифрованного сообщения 

{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        if (j == a - 1)
            j = 0;
        if (text[i] != 32)
        {
            if (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z')
            {
                if (key[j] >= 'A' && key[j] <= 'Z')
                {
                    text[i] = ((text[i] - key[j] + 26) % 26) + 65;
                    j++;
                }
                else if (key[j] >= 'a' && key[j] <= 'z')
                {
                    text[i] = text[i] + 32;
                    text[i] = ((text[i] - key[j] + 26) % 26) + 65;
                    j++;
                }
            }
            else if (text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z')
            {
                if (key[j] >= 'a' && key[j] <= 'z')
                {
                    text[i] = ((text[i] - key[j] + 26) % 26) + 97;
                    j++;
                }
                else if (key[j] >= 'A' && key[j] <= 'Z')
                {
                    text[i] = text[i] - 32;
                    text[i] = ((text[i] - key[j] + 26) % 26) + 97;
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return j;
}

int main()
{
    char started_string[STR_LEN + 1] = "";
    char encrypted_string[STR_LEN + 1] = "";

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    Output_Start_Info();
    switch (Type_Of_Work())
    {
        case 1: 
                Input_Start_String(started_string);
                Encryption_Viz(started_string, encrypted_string);
                break;

        case 2: 
                Input_Start_String(started_string); 
                Decryption();
                break;

        default: printf("Проверьте правильность введного ключа.");
                break;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Быстренько просмотрел программку и вот какие замечания:

1) В функции **Input_Start_String** у тебя есть **scanf_s("%i", &key)**. Эта функция считает из буфера stdin число, но оставит в буфере несчитанным символ "\n" (символ перевода каретки). В итоге после вывода приглашения "Пожалуйста введите текст, который хотите де-/за-шифровать..." при чтении текста в функции **Input_By_Yourself** самый первый считанный символ будет оставшийся в буфере "\n". Но при повторном вызове функции Input_By_Yourself для считывания ключа шифрования символа "\n" уже не будет в буфере, поэтому командой **getchar()** считается тупо первый символ ключа, в итоге строка ключа считается без первого символа. РЕШЕНИЕ: убрать вызов **getchar()** из функции **Input_By_Yourself** и прописать вызов функции **getchar()** стразу после **scanf_s("%i", &key)** в функции **Input_Start_String**:

```
/* In function Input_Start_String() */
scanf_s("%i", &key);
getchar();
switch (key)
{
    ...
}
```

2) В функции **Encryption_Viz** ты статически создаёшь строку, которая будет состоять только из 2-х символов (это пробе и затем символ завершения строки '\0'). Но при этом пишешь туда все символы из строки s!!! так как ты не можешь знать в момент компилляции размера long_string (так как он зависит от длинны строки для шифрования), то единственный способ не допустить переполнение - это выделить для long_string память динамически!!!

```
void Encryption_Viz(char *started_string, char *encrypte_string)
{
    char key[STR_LEN] = " ";
    printf("\n\nВведите ключ для шифрования: ");
    Input_By_Yourself(key);
    int s = strlen(started_string);
    int e = strlen(key);

    char *long_string = (char *)malloc((s + 1) * sizeof(char));

    if (s >= e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
        {
            long_string[i] = key[((e + 1) % (i + 1))];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
        {
            long_string[i] += key[i];
        }
    }
    long_string[s + 1] = '\0';
    printf("%s ", long_string);
    free(long_string)
}
```

Обрати внимание на функцию выделения (malloc) и очистки (free) динамической памяти.